# Control CSS via JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, css, onmouseover

I am looking for a way to control the CSS for a specific item on hover. Since it's not an element directly in the parent lineage, I can't use CSS.

```
<article class="portfolio-item web">
  <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://vimeo.com/34266952">
    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/.../images/portfolio/introspection.jpg" alt="">
    <span class="genericBeaconIsotope">
      <span class="beaconContainer">
        <span class="beaconBar"></span>
        <span class="beaconCircle1"></span>
        <span class="beaconCircle2"></span>
        <span class="beaconText">Introspection</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </a>
</article>
```

I'm trying to hover on beaconContainer and have the image be affected. It should function like a rollover. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish in CSS:

```
    -webkit-transform: scale(10);    
    -moz-transform: scale(10);    
    -o-transform: scale(10);    
    -ms-transform: scale(10); 
    transform: scale(10);    
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

How would I go about doing this? I know very little JavaScript or jQuery or how to call events from them, especially like this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

JQuery provides several methods which may be helpful to you.

You could go about manually setting the CSS using the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method, or apply CSS classes dynamically to the elements (this is would be my preferred way) using the [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) methods, reacting to user events such as mouse overs, etc.

**NB:** This is *specifically* a jQuery solution to the problem presented by your question.

Comment: only applies to the jQuery library.  You should mention that.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can use the addClass and removeClass functions. Keep all of the css in the css file, and then just change the class of each element.

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CSS class with the styles you want to apply:

```
.rollover {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

and a bit of jQuery that enabled your styles when mouse is over the beaconContainer:

```
$('article.portfolio-item.web').each(function(index, articleElem) {
   var article = $(articleElem);
   var image = article.find('img');
   var container = article.find('.beaconContainer');
   container.mouseover(function() { image.addClass("rollover"); });
   container.mouseout(function() { image.removeClass("rollover"); });
});
```

It will also work if you have multiple articles on page.

Comment: I'm new to this site, so I can't rate this answer, but please give Maciej positive feedback for me. This answer worked just like I needed it to. I'm not entirely sure how it knows that it's a "this" element that it needs to affect, but it works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the CSS class and then add it to the container when you hover and then remove the class once you mouse out:

```
$('.beaconContainer img').hover(function(){
    $( this ).addClass(cssClassName);
  }, function() {
   $( this ).removeClass(cssClassName);
  }
);
```

Comment: He wants to affect the image, not the `beaconContainer`. Otherwise you really shouldn't use jQuery for this.

Comment: Thanks, but he's right. I would use CSS to control it, except that it's not in the direct hierarchy. It's up a few levels and then it's a child of a sibling element.